# Pasting a screenshot into Powerpoint results in truncation: even though in MSWord it is perfect

Tags: ms-office, copy-paste

The following is an image representing the source of a clipboard cut and paste operation.  Actually the image shows up *better* in MsWord: here it is blurry

[image]

However it is *much* worse in PowerPoint when pasted either from (a) the clipboard or (b) first to Word, copy into clipboard again and then paste into Powerpoint: in fact it is truncated

[image]

So .. what is the deal with pasting to PowerPoint ?  I am using PP for Mac 2011 v 14.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there were a  toolbar at the bottom of the screen that **only shows up after you click once on the (messed up) screenshot** and has an ***impressively unhelpful*** default value set.  Below I show having finally randomly clicked on the correct icon:

[image]

Now *why the picture would not be* already *sized properly* .. well we can (un)-thank the PP designers for that.